# PHP Posting Data to Touchnet

Tags: php, html, forms, post, curl

I'm trying to redirect the user to touchnet's upay site after they have registered on my site. So this is what my site looks like:

```
Registration.php
     |This is where the user will register for an account along with providing their information
Insert.php
     |This is the script that will take all the data posted from `Registration.php`'s form and insert them into the database. But it is also the script that will send the user to the payment page
touchnet
     |This is the site that will receive the posted data from `Insert.php` and take care of payment.
```

So here's my curl settings:

```
$url='https://secure.touchnet.com:*/Something/*/*.jsp';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

But when the insert finished inserting data and redirects using curl it actually goes to `www.domain.com/Something/tapp`, `www.domain.com` being my website. And the browser says `/Something` not found, obviously because it's not even going to the correct url. Why is cURL failing to redirect to the proper url?

Comment: @Raidenace your guess is as good as mine. I have no idea where that tapp is coming from. I just want to redirect the user to the payment site, posting important data along with them (such as payment amount), is cURL not a good option for this?

Comment: ok, lemme answer below..easier than typing lengthy comments :)